# Add owner to M365 group in AAD programmatically

Tags: typescript, react-redux, azure-active-directory

I have an application in Azure Active Directory.

[image]

I need to add this application as an owner of a M365 group (I am an owner of M365 group) in AAD? How do I do that programmatically via a React/TypeScript application?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a multi step process what you have to follow. It consists of the following steps:

1. Get the App ID of the App Registration
2. Get the Identity assigned to the App Registration (for details regarding service principals, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals)
3. Get the Group ID you want to add the App as an owner
4. Assign the Identity as a Group owner

For all the steps, we will use the graphAPI, for which you can find documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0. All queries you can test for your environment with the help of https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Note that there is an SDK available for Typescript: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript

The following shows you how each step can be achived. By inserting the queries in Graph Explorer, you can adapt them and also generate the Code Snippets which use the aforementioned SDK. For this reason, I will state the API Endpoints below and not the javascript code.

#### Get the App ID

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$filter=displayName eq 'test-user-app'&$select=displayName,appId`

This gives you a list of objects containing the displayName and appID of all applications which are equal to 'test-user-app' - it should only be one, and therefore you can easily get the app id. Make sure to store it in a variable. If the App Id does not change, you may want to specify it explicitly.

#### Get Service Principals ID

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals(appId='insert-the-app-id-variable-here')?$select=id`

This returns you an object containing a field 'id', which is the id of the identity used by the applicaiton. Again, make sure to store it in a variable like servicePrincipalId.

#### Get group object

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName eq '11-23-t1'&$select=displayName,id`

This again gives you a list of objects with only those groups (id and displayName) with the name 11-23-t1, which again should only be one. Make sure to store the id in a variable again.

#### Set service principal as group owner

This time, you have to create a POST request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id-which-you-got-in-the-step-before}/owners/$ref
Content-type: application/json

{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id-of-the-service-principal}"
}
```

If you get a response code of 200, you successfully set the owner. Give Microsoft/Azure some time to update everything and you will be able to see it.